# Controlling Program with MQTT and Python

Tags: python, mqtt, payload, paho

Yo, guys. So I'm relatively new to Python and a complete newbie with MQTT. So, I'm trying to make a simple connection of two programs via MQTT. One of the programs is the publisher:

```
   import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
   import sys, tty, termios 
   ## Publisher reads a keyboard input 
   def getch():
       fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
       old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
       try:
           tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
           ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
       finally:
           termios.tcsetattr(fd,termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
           return ch

   while True:
   ##Publisher connects to MQTT broker
       mqttc= mqtt.Client("python_pub")
       mqttc.connect("iot.eclipse.org", 1883)
       char= getch()
       mqttc.publish("Labbo/control", str(char))
       mqtt.Client()
```

So, basically the publisher reads a key input and sends it to the broker. 
And the client program is supposed to read the key stroke and react accordingly:

```
   import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

   def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
       print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
       client.subscribe("Labbo/control")

   def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
       print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))
   ## v v PROBLEM LINE v v ## 
   char=str(msg.payload)
   ## ^ ^ PROBLEM LINE ^ ^ ##
   client = mqtt.Client()
   client.on_connect = on_connect
   client.on_message = on_message  
   client.connect("iot.eclipse.org", 1883, 60)
   ##The program just needs to close itself upon entering "x" on the Publisher
   while True:
       if char=="x":
          break
```

This is a simple test program but I've been having a lot of trouble trying to "read" the MQTT payload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Subscriber code is looping without doing anything productive. It must be changed as follows

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
   print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
   client.subscribe("Labbo/control")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
   print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))
   char = str(msg.payload)
   if char == 'x':
       client.disconnect()

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect("iot.eclipse.org", 1883, 60)
client.loop_forever()
```

So is your Publisher code where it create a new client to send a single letter which is kind of a overkill

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import sys, tty, termios
## Publisher reads a keyboard input 
def getch():
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    try:
        tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
        ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd,termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
    return ch


##Publisher connects to MQTT broker
mqttc= mqtt.Client("python_pub")
mqttc.connect("iot.eclipse.org", 1883)
mqttc.loop_start()

while True:
    char= getch()
    mqttc.publish("Labbo/control", str(char))
```

Comment: The Publisher code should also call the mqttc.start_loop() before entering the while True: loop to ensure keep-alive messages are sent and that large publishes could be handled (not actually required in this case, but good form)