# MQTT and time delay

Tags: python, time, mqtt, paho

I have a python script which I am trying to work with paho mqtt and time delay. I have looked into similar questions which discuss paho mqtt like [Controlling Program with MQTT and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30318248/controlling-program-with-mqtt-and-python). My python script is as follows:

Here is my script:

```
    import paho.mqtt.client as mqttClient
    import time
    import subprocess
    import os
    
    
    global lastprocessed, Connected
    lastprocessed = None
    Connected = False   #global variable for the state of the connection
    
    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
        if rc == 0:
            print("Connected to broker")
            global Connected
            Connected = True                #Signal connection
        else:
            print("Connection failed")
    
    
    def on_message(client, userdata, message):
        global lastprocessed
        if message.payload.decode() == "hello":
            lastprocessed = time.time()
    
        if lastprocessed and time.time() - lastprocessed < 20:
            print("good")

broker_address= "192.168.1.111"  #Broker address
port = 1883                         #Broker port
user = "abcde"                    #Connection username
password = "12345"            #Connection password

client = mqttClient.Client("Python")               #create new instance
client.username_pw_set(user, password=password)    #set username and password
client.on_connect= on_connect                      #attach function to callback
client.on_message= on_message                      #attach function to callback
client.connect(broker_address,port,60) #connect
client.subscribe("home/OpenMQTTGateway/433toMQTT") #subscribe
client.loop_forever() #then keep listening forever
```

What is happening with my code above is that, whenever "hello" is received in the payload it prints "good" but if anything else is received in the payload including "hello" it continues printing "good". It doesn't take into consideration the time of 20 seconds. I am not sure why?

What I am trying to achieve is the following:

1. When the python script is executed at the beginning, the script should print "bad".
2. This should stop until "hello" is received in the payload.
3. Once "hello" is received, "good" should be printed for 20 seconds and during those 20 seconds any other messages received in the topic should be ignored including "hello".
4. After the 20 seconds, the script should continue printing "bad" but only once and the cycle continues.

**Updated question 24/03/2021:**

So my new script below keeps printing "Connected to Broker" initially it wasnt and I havent changed anything but now somehow it keeps printing and the if statements are not executed at all.

I know my script worked fine but I just need the if statements to be executed and the continuous loop i.e. continuous printing of "Connected to Broker" to stop.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqttClient
import time
import subprocess
import os
import json


global lastprocessed, Connected
lastprocessed = None
Connected = False   #global variable for the state of the connection

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc == 0:
        print("Connected to broker")
        global Connected
        Connected = True                #Signal connection
    else:
        print("Connection failed")


x = y = 0

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    global x, y

    global lastprocessed

    a = str(message.payload)

    data = json.loads(a);

    j = data["contact"]
    print(j)

    if j == False:
        x += 1
        print(x)
    if j == True:
        y += 1
        print(y)
    if x == 1 or x == 0 and y == 1:
        os.system("vcgencmd display_power 1")
    if y == 2:
        x = y = 0
        os.system("vcgencmd display_power 0")

broker_address= "192.168.XXX.XXX"  #Broker address
port = 1883                         #Broker port
user = "XXXX"                    #Connection username
password = "XXXX"            #Connection password

client = mqttClient.Client("Python")               #create new instance
client.username_pw_set(user, password=password)    #set username and password
client.on_connect= on_connect                      #attach function to callback
client.on_message= on_message                      #attach function to callback
client.connect(broker_address,port,60) #connect
client.subscribe("zigbee2mqtt/Xiaomi Door Sensor 2") #subscribe
client.loop_forever() #then keep listening forever
```

Comment: maybe you should use `while lastprocessed and time.time() - lastprocessed < 20:` or simply `time.sleep(20)`

Comment: @furas I tried that but it still gives me the same problem.

Comment: I would rather create own loop instead of `loop_forever` and this loop would check if there is new message and if not then it would print `bad` or repeate printing `good` and it would check time (in every loop) to stop printing `good`.

Comment: BTW: we use `global` only inside function to inform function that it has to use external/global variable. All variables created outside function are global and using `global` outside function is useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `loop_start()` and `loop_stop()` instead of `loop_forever()` and then between `start` and `stop` I can create own loop which can check messages and print text.

I use variable `state` to control if code is before first `hello` (`state = "start"`) or it gets `hello` and now it has to check time and repeate text "good" (`state = "hello"`) or it has 20 seconds after `hello` and it has print nothing (`state = "other")`

Inside `on_message` I only change state to `hello` when I get message `hello` and old state is different then `hello`.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqttClient
import time

# --- functions ---

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    #global state
    global connected

    if rc == 0:
        print("Connected to broker")
        connected = True                
    else:
        print("Connection failed")

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    global state
    global last_processed
    
    if message.payload.decode() == "hello":
        if state != 'hello':
            state = 'hello'
            last_processed = time.time()

    # OR
    
    #if state != 'hello':
    #    if message.payload.decode() == "hello":
    #        state = 'hello'
    #        last_processed = time.time()

# --- main ---

broker_address = "192.168.1.111"  # broker address
port = 1883                       # broker port
user = "abcde"                    # connection username
password = "12345"                # connection password

# ---

client = mqttClient.Client("Python")               # create new instance
client.username_pw_set(user, password=password)    # set username and password
client.on_connect= on_connect                      # attach function to callback
client.on_message= on_message                      # attach function to callback
client.connect(broker_address, port, 60)           # connect
client.subscribe("home/OpenMQTTGateway/433toMQTT") # subscribe

# --- main loop ---

last_processed = None
connected = False      # signal connection
state = 'start' # 'start', 'hello', 'other', 'not connected'   

# ---

client.loop_start()

try:
    while True:
        if not connected:
            print('not connected')
            
        if state == 'start':
            print('bad')
            
        if state == 'hello':
            if last_processed and time.time() - last_processed < 20:
                print("good", time.time() - last_processed, end='\r') # '\r` to write it in the same line.
            else:
                print('bad')
                state = 'other'
                last_processed = None
        
        if state == 'other':
            pass
    
        time.sleep(1.0) # to slow down example
        
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('KeyboardInterrupt')
    
client.loop_stop()
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you need `bad` and `hello` only once then you can print first `bad` before loop, and `hello` when you get message and then `time.sleep(20)` before you print `bad` and change steate.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqttClient
import time

# --- functions ---

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    #global state
    global connected

    if rc == 0:
        print("Connected to broker")
        connected = True                
    else:
        print("Connection failed")

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    global state

    message = message.payload.decode()
    
    if state != 'hello':
        if message == 'hello':
            state = 'hello'
            print('good') # once when start `hello`
        else:
            print('msg:', message)        

# --- main ---

broker_address = "192.168.1.111"  # broker address
port = 1883                       # broker port
user = "abcde"                    # connection username
password = "12345"                # connection password

# ---

client = mqttClient.Client("Python")               # create new instance
client.username_pw_set(user, password=password)    # set username and password
client.on_connect= on_connect                      # attach function to callback
client.on_message= on_message                      # attach function to callback
client.connect(broker_address, port, 60)           # connect
client.subscribe("home/OpenMQTTGateway/433toMQTT") # subscribe

# --- main loop ---

connected = False      # signal connection
state = 'other' # 'hello'

# ---

client.loop_start()

print('bad') # once at start

try:
    while True:
        
        if state == 'hello':
            time.sleep(20)
            print('bad')  # once when end `hello`
            state = 'other'
    
        time.sleep(1.0) # to slow down example
        
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('KeyboardInterrupt')
    
client.loop_stop()
```

It would be useful to use `threading.Timer` instead of `time.sleep()` because `sleep()` blocks loop and it is not so useful if you want to do something more.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqttClient
import threading

# --- functions ---

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    #global state
    global connected

    if rc == 0:
        print("Connected to broker")
        connected = True                
    else:
        print("Connection failed")

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    global state

    message = message.payload.decode()
    
    if state != 'hello':
        if message == 'hello':
            state = 'hello'
            print('good') # once when start `hello`
            threading.Timer(20, end_hello).start()
        else:
            print('msg:', message)
        
def end_hello():
    global state
    
    print('bad')  # once when end `hello`
    state = 'other'

# --- main ---

broker_address = "192.168.1.111"  # broker address
port = 1883                       # broker port
user = "abcde"                    # connection username
password = "12345"                # connection password

# ---

client = mqttClient.Client("Python")               # create new instance
client.username_pw_set(user, password=password)    # set username and password
client.on_connect= on_connect                      # attach function to callback
client.on_message= on_message                      # attach function to callback
client.connect(broker_address, port, 60)           # connect
client.subscribe("home/OpenMQTTGateway/433toMQTT") # subscribe

# --- main loop ---

connected = False      # signal connection
state = 'other' # 'hello'

# ---

print('bad') # once at start
client.loop_forever()
```

Eventually you can still check time in loop

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqttClient
import time

# --- functions ---

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    #global state
    global connected

    if rc == 0:
        print("Connected to broker")
        connected = True                
    else:
        print("Connection failed")

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    global state
    global last_processed
    
    message = message.payload.decode()
    
    if state != 'hello':
        if message == 'hello':
            state = 'hello'
            last_processed = time.time()
            print('good') # once when start `hello`
        else:
            print('msg:', message)        

# --- main ---

broker_address = "192.168.1.111"  # broker address
port = 1883                       # broker port
user = "abcde"                    # connection username
password = "12345"                # connection password

# ---

client = mqttClient.Client("Python")               # create new instance
client.username_pw_set(user, password=password)    # set username and password
client.on_connect= on_connect                      # attach function to callback
client.on_message= on_message                      # attach function to callback
client.connect(broker_address, port, 60)           # connect
client.subscribe("home/OpenMQTTGateway/433toMQTT") # subscribe

# --- main loop ---

last_processed = None
connected = False      # signal connection
state = 'other' # 'hello'

# ---

client.loop_start()

print('bad') # once at start

try:
    while True:
        
        if state == 'hello':
            if time.time() >= last_processed + 20:
                print('bad')  # once when end `hello`
                state = 'other'
    
        time.sleep(1.0) # to slow down example
        
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('KeyboardInterrupt')
    
client.loop_stop()
```

Comment: Hi @furas thank you for the answer :) It works as expected, however I know we have used a while statement and it keeps looping and printing "bad" or "good". How can I improve the code to just print "bad" or "good" only once? Thanks once again buddy

Comment: it seems I misunderstood writing out - I thought you want to print it many times. But it still may need `while`-loop to check time

Comment: I added new examples - with `sleep`, `threading.Timer` and `loop`.

Comment: thank you ever so much buddy. I used the `threading.Timer` method and it works better for me. I will look into it further on how it works. Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: when I runt the python script continuously in crontab the script stops working and it does not print "good" or "bad" when the "hello" payload is received until I restart my raspberry pi linux. Is this something to do with python or?

Comment: `crontab` is used to run programs without access to console (ie. it can run code when you are not even logged in to system) so it can't display anything. You can eventually redirect output to file (or use module `logging` to save in file) and check what you have in file.

Comment: Thats correct. However I have modified the code to turn my TV on or off depending on what I receive on the payload.

Comment: crontab may not have access to desktop to display anything. If you want to display something in console or GUI then you should rather run it manually or using `autostart` to run programs after logged in.

Comment: Oh right I see. Is there a better way to run the script in background continuously?

Comment: if you want to display then you have to start it manually in console. If you run Linux with GUI then you can eventually use autostart [Autorun a program in Pixel desktop after login](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=183479)

Comment: basically the python code that you helped me with, when it receives a command in the payload instead of printing good it turns the screen on which my raspberry pi is connected to for 4 minutes and then turns it off i.e print ("bad"). I dont think paho mqtt python library works with cronjob. Also I gave all rights to the above python script on my raspberry but it still doesnt work with cronjob. It works fine when I manually run it on terminal.

Comment: ok I sorted it by using systemd and it works fine now. Many thanks again :)

Comment: Hey @furas I am trying to decode my message payload which contains several items in it. How can I decode and print a specific item from the message payload?

Comment: I don't know what you send but it can send only string and if you want to send something more complex (list or dictionary) then you could use `JSON` to covert list/dicionary to string and later convert back string to list/dictionary. OR you could convert all items to one string with elements separaded by unique char (ie. `;` or `|` or `#`) and later it is easy to split this string into elements.

Comment: so this is what I have modified: 

`def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    global lastprocessed

    a = str(message.payload)


    print(a)

   
    data = json.loads(a)

    print(data)

    j = data['"contact"']

    print(j) `

This is what I get as a JSON message when I subscribe to the topic: 

`{"battery":100,"contact":true,"linkquality":78,"voltage":3055}`

I am trying to derive the value of `contact:`

Comment: it should be `data['contact']` without `" "`. Or `data["contact"]` without `' '`

Comment: hey @furas the decoded message that I have produced 2 values either true or false. I am trying to assign a variable x and y so that when it is true x = 1 and when it is false y = 1. Its working well so far however, the next step is when x = 1 and y = 1 I need it to e.g. print("good") and when x = 2  I need it to print("bad") and reset the values of x and y to 0. I am stuck with the first part i.e. when x and y = 1 as it is not printing good. I suppose for the latter I need to use a while loop with x = 2. Can you please provide some insight on this?

Comment: if you have new preblem then better create new question on new page and you will have more space to show all code and it will be better formatted. But if you use code `if x and y == 1:` then you are wrong - it has to be `if x == 1 and y == 1:`

Comment: I have tried what you suggested but it didnt work for me. And I cannot post a new question as for some reason my account is restricted. I have been asked to edit my question(s) which I have now and hoping the restrictions to be lifted.

Comment: Hey @furas on a different note, my script keeps on looping and printing "Connected to Broker". I have updated the question and provided the new script can you please look into it for me? thanks.

Comment: BTW: better use parenthesis  to make sure if  you want `if (x == 1 or x == 0) and y == 1:` or `if x == 1 or (x == 0 and y == 1):`

Comment: I agree with what you are saying but as I mentioned before I cannot make a new question otherwise I would have done it by now. I have already shown my new code in this question and it has fitted perfectly well.

It is the same question only the architecture is different. Again I would have put it in a new question but Stackover Flow has restricted my account in asking any question.

Comment: don't you see button `"Add Question"` on the top ? it should create new question on new page (not on current page). `Stackoverflow` is not `forum` which can have many questions on one page.

Comment: I think the problem in the code is that it is a loop which keeps on printing "Connected to the broker" the if statements that you mentioned are not getting executed at all. I am trying to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: if you get  "Connected to the broker" many times then maybe problem is server - maybe it disconnects your client and client has to connect again and again.

Comment: please see this link when I press Add Question at the top. https://imgur.com/wjbcSUc

Comment: I was thinking it could be due to function or the global. As the server is running fine and I dont think there is a connection issue as many other things are connected to my MQTT server and they are all working fine.

Comment: code seems OK. But first I would check `print( client, userdata, message )` in `on_message` to see if this function is executed and if it gets data which you expect. Maybe It gets data different then you expect. OR you send values as strings - `"False"`,`"0"`, `"1"` but later you compare them with boolean `False` and integer `0`, `1`.

Comment: how do I print in `on_message`?